# Django : Get specific columns from multiple tables

Tags: django, django-models

I need to fetch columns from multiple tables, how do I achieve this?

```
UserLog


+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| log_id     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| time       | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address | char(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| event_id   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Events


+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| event_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my  `models.py`

```
class Events(models.Model):
        event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,verbose_name="Event id")
        description = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Description")

        def __unicode__(self):
                return u"%d : %s" % (self.event_id, self.description)

class UserLog(models.Model):
        log_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        event = models.ForeignKey(Events,verbose_name = "event")
        time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
        ip_address = models.IPAddressField(null=True)


        def __unicode__(self):
                return u"%s (%s): %s" % (self.log_id, self.user, self.event)
```

Spcifically I want to do 
`SELECT log_id,time,user_id,event_id,description from UserLog,Events where UserLog.event_id = Events.event_id`

I tried `UserLog.objects.filter(event_id__event_id).values('log_id','time','user_id','event_id','description')` . But it says no such fields.

Is there something I need to change in my models class?

Comment: Can you post your django model code?

Comment: Oops, that was supposed to be `Events`. Updated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
UserLog.objects.filter(event_id=1).values('log_id', 
                                          'time',
                                          'user_id',
                                          'event_id', 
                                          'event__description')
```

Alternately, you could use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
UserLog.objects.filter(event__id=1).select_related('event')
```

then you'll get `UserLog` objects, with the event pre-fetched, so you can access the event without triggering another query.

(Also, standard naming convention would be to call the model `Event`, not `Events`)

Comment: That worked! Dumb enough, I forgot to access the other tables fields by `foreignkey_fields`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) like this:

```
UserLog.objects.filter(event_id__event_id=1).select_related('event').values('log_id','time','user_id','event_id', 'event__description')
```

Comment: That was quick! 
I tried this
`UserLog.objects.filter(event_id__event_id=1).select_related('description').values()`


And i got 
`[{'log_id': 4L, u'event_id': 1L, 'ip_address': u'10.100.32.142', u'user_id': 2L, 'time': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 25, 21, 29, 28, tzinfo=<UTC>)}`

'Description' field isn't being displayed!

Comment: You are right, I was trying to incorrectly access fields from other tables.

Comment: Guys could you please help me resolve this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587819/django-keyerror-while-fetching-multiple-tables?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

```
dataStudent =  Studentinfo.objects.select_related().values(
    'country__countryname',
    'state__statename', 
    'city__cityname',
    'id','studentname',
    'rollno',
    'email',
    'phoneno')
```

in the **`country__countryname`** country is the **`name`** of field              when u define the relationship like follow

```
city =  models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
state =  models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
country =  models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and **`countryname`** is the table field inside the **`country`** table and
same as **`state__statename`** and **`city__cityname`**

and other fields are from **`Studentinfo`** model

so that will give me the following result

[image]